# Changing font of non-monospace text in Emacs

Tags: fonts, font-lock

I see variable and function names in Info pages rendered with a different font in Emacs recently, how can I change this font?

[image: Sample Image]

For example, here ^ `this-comamnd` and `last-command` are in a font. I would like to customize this font. I think this same font is used in `eww` and I find it ugly, eww.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your text cursor on that text, then use `C-u` `C-x` `=` (`what-cursor-position`) to see what face it's using. I believe it's using `Info-quoted` in this instance. You can then `M-x` `customize-face` to change it.